# How do I get reputation

Tags: discussion

It really sucks that I can't vote up or comment.

I'm sure the concept of reputation is fine for early adopters, but to late comers, it's just a pain.

Comment: My suggestion (too tiny to be an answer, I guess) would be for you to scan http://drupal.stackexchange.com/unanswered for questions you can answer :)

Comment: Early adopter or not you have to do the same things to earn reputation.

Comment: @rooby actually early adopters have a problem - on early stage hardly anyone can vote, accepting is the only one available to all way to give reputation, and so on ;) I think medium - level sites like this are best. Stack Overflow is a pains in it's own right, as an old, established, and really big site.

Comment: "You must have at least 5 reputation on Drupal Answers to answer a question." GAAAAA!

Answer (score 8):

First of all, welcome :)

I have to disagree with it being a "pain" to earn enough reputation to participate in the ways you're suggesting.

You need a *tiny* 15 reputation points to upvote, and a similarly tiny 50 points to post comments. These miniscule requirements ensure that you are initially able to contribute **positively** to the site. It stops people dropping by and leaving off-topic/un-constructive comments, or skewing voting tallies without having proved they know enough for their vote to be considered valid.

The date of your arrival has nothing to do with it either - it would take no more than 2 or 3 quality contributions to the site for you to earn enough rep to vote up and comment, which would take very little time to do.

If you ask a good question, it would only need 3 upvotes before you reach the 15 mark and can vote up. Up-voted answers will earn 10 points each, and an acceptance to an answer 15 points. Any combination of those can be used to bolster your rep points; hopefully that shows quite how low the barrier for entry is here. A couple of decent questions/answers and you're away - you just need to show that you're going to be a positive influence on the site.

The reason for the barrier itself is simple - it's just another one of our (many) quality controls. Everyone benefits from this as it means the quality on the site will be higher than it would otherwise be, if we had no such controls.

I can understand the frustration of having had an answer deleted (if that's what happened) if you posted a comment there, but hopefully now that you know the reasons for the deletion it will make more sense.

Comment: Right, being here at the beginning doesn't automatically mean to be a high reputation user. There are users who joined later who have more reputation of those users who participated at the beginning or since the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to grab 15 minimum points to start up-voting, the easiest way to get is answer any question which will make you earn 10 points on up-voting and 15 points when accepted.You can also earn points by asking question which if up-voted will make your earn 5 points.

An easy way to understand the system will be why you need money to buy something. I consider this 15 points minimum limit is to avoid fake accounts to up-vote their own answers which causes right answers to go down and fake up-voted answers to go up which in turn spoils the whole concept of helping and get helped with good answers. It is really required to keep the system clean and encourage people to provide assistance in long run. You will better understand this when start answering the questions.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [**help page**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) everything mentioned there and below is the quick answer to your post

**You gain reputation when:**

> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> - bounty awarded to your answer: +full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

Comment: Yes I know this. That's what I'm complaining about.

Comment: So what do you expect other than this method. You mean you want to access everything without contributing to DA, if so then you need to post a question in meta stackoverflow

Comment: @DanBolser Just complaining isn't useful to anyone. Instead, suggest a solution to your perceived problem. Obviously we can't just drop the rep requirements, because spammers and nefarious users would be able to post and vote at-will. What is your proposed solution for your problem?

Comment: That's a fair question. I don't have a specific suggestion, but I think the barrier is too high to casual users visiting mature sites. I think the perceived threat to quality is much lower than you think, as the majority of the users will be honest (like me).

I'd like to suggest you try creating a new account and then keep using SA as you would with your regular account and see how long it takes to get reputation. See how arbitrary the restrictions are.

Comment: I found it frustrating as well, that I'd had to build reputation from scratch on several different sites to be able to comment/etc. on them. However, once I reached 200 points on one site, I got the site association bonus, and will now start with 100 point on each of the sister sites. I achieved this on a site whose users are generous with up-voting and where I have fun answering questions and doing research.